# Is it possible to write an end-to-end test for an Apex method which schedules an asynchronous/future callout?

Tags: apex, unit-test, scheduled-apex, callout, future

I have the following class:

```
    global class WarehouseSyncSchedule implements Schedulable {

    global void execute(SchedulableContext schedulableContext) {
        WarehouseCalloutService.runWarehouseEquipmentSync();
    }

    public static Id scheduleMorningRun() {
        Integer pstTargetHour = 1; // 24 hour time
        Integer pstOffset = -8;
        Integer userOffset = UserInfo.getTimeZone().getOffset(Date.today());
        Integer userTime = Math.mod(pstTargetHour - pstOffset + userOffSet, 24);  

        String schedule = '0 0 ' + userTime + ' * * ?';
        return System.schedule('Warehouse Sync', schedule, new WarehouseSyncSchedule());
    }
}
```

I wanted to create a test for the `scheduleMorningRun()` method, so I created the following test method:

```
@isTest
private class WarehouseSyncScheduleTest {
    private static final User TestRunner = TEST_RunAsUserFactory.create(); 

    @isTest static void testScheduleMorningRun(){
        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new WarehouseCalloutServiceMock());

        Id resultJobId;
        Test.startTest();
        {
            resultJobId = WarehouseSyncSchedule.scheduleMorningRun(); 
        }
        Test.stopTest();

        // TODO: Assertions
    }        
}
```

Unfortunately, this fails with:

> System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please
>   commit or rollback before calling out

The `scheduleMorningRun()` method actually works, as does `WarehouseSyncSchedule.execute()`.

Any ideas how I can successfully create a functioning unit test for it?

... In case it may help, here is some more of the relevant code:

```
public with sharing virtual class WarehouseCalloutService {
    private static final String WAREHOUSE_URL = 'https://th-superbadge-apex.herokuapp.com/equipment';

    HWR_WarehouseCalloutStrategy warehouseCalloutStrategy;

    public WarehouseCalloutService(HWR_WarehouseCalloutStrategy warehouseCalloutStrategy) {
        this.warehouseCalloutStrategy = warehouseCalloutStrategy;
    }

    public WarehouseCalloutService() {
        this(new HWR_WarehouseCalloutStrategy(WAREHOUSE_URL));
    }

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void runWarehouseEquipmentSync(){
        (new WarehouseCalloutService()).syncEquipment();
    }

    public virtual void syncEquipment() {
        this.warehouseCalloutStrategy.execute();
    }

}


    public virtual class HWR_WarehouseCalloutStrategy extends HTTP_RestfulCalloutStrategy { 
/* Implementation here */ 
}

public abstract class HTTP_RestfulCalloutStrategy implements HTTP_RestfulCalloutStrategyInterface {
    private String endpoint; 
    public Integer targetId {get; set;}
    public String method {get; set;}
    public String contentType {get; set;}
    public String body {get; set;}
    public Set<Integer> successCodeSet = new Set<Integer>{ 200 }; 

    public HTTP_RestfulCalloutStrategy(String endpoint){
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    public HttpResponse execute() { 
        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest httpRequest = createRequest();

        HttpResponse response = http.send(httpRequest);
        return (!(this.successCodeSet.contains(response.getStatusCode()))) 
            ? onFailure(response)
            : onSuccess(response);
    }

    @testVisible     
    private HttpRequest createRequest() {
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();

        String endpoint = this.endpoint;
        if (targetId != null) {
            endpoint += '/' + targetId;
        }
        request.setEndpoint(endpoint);

        String method = (!String.isBlank(this.method)) ? this.method : 'GET'; 
        request.setMethod(method);

        if (!String.isBlank(this.contentType)){
            request.setHeader('Content-Type', this.contentType);
        }

        if (!String.isBlank(this.body)){
            request.setBody(this.body);
        }
        return request;
    }   


    public abstract HttpResponse onSuccess(HttpResponse response);

    public virtual HttpResponse onFailure(HttpResponse response) {
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.ERROR, 'Unexpected Response: ' + response.toString());
        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53781/discussion-on-question-by-brian-kessler-is-it-possible-to-write-an-end-to-end-te).

Comment: Please continue any discussion in chat.